# How can I stop the main window from displaying a scroll bar when a modal is activated?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.1

When a modal is activated I get a scroll bar appear. In some situations it even shifts the content over to the left, completely ruining the effect.

I've tried setting the main body  so that it always has a scroll bar, but then I get two.

Here is an example.

http://nu11.co.uk/modal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.modal` class has the following CSS rules:

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1040;
    display: none;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

The scrollbar is because of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` lines.

Assuming that you call bootstrap.css from CDN, if you hack this rule in the head tag on the page after linking bootsrap.css, the scrollbar will be vanished:

```
<head>
    .
    .
    .
    <link href="/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    .
    .
    .
    <style>
        .modal {
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    .
    .
    .
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks Özkan ÖZLÜ. I added the "body.modal-open, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom", not because it fixes this exact example but because I resolved the issue I had with the content shifting over to left.